# .rep Report File - Find Report Builder

Tags: delphi, report

I have an old software that I believe was done in Delphi and uses .rep files for reports. 
Is there any way to figure out what report builder was used? Opening the file in HEX or Text only doesn't really tell a lot, it shows quite some text that is used within the report though.

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: As far as I know none of default reporting components that were shipped with delphi use *.rep file extension. So I suggest you first check to see if the program was actually made with Delphi. If there was no encription or archiving done on executable you could determine that using a neat program called PE Explorer http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm
If the program was made with Delphi PE explorer would be even able to tell you which version was used (works for version of Delphi 7 and older, not sure for newer). Use that info to track which reporting components were available then.

Comment: Take a look at the properties of the file (I assume you are on Windows) - you may find information about the author, vendor etc. You you should also be able to see such information in the text portions when you open it in a hex editor - particularly at the very top or bottom of the file.

Comment: With PE Explorer I wasn't able to see the version, but an entry with Licence valid, Delphi Client/Server Suite (Enterprise). Thus I believe Delphi should be right. I don't believe they have done their own reporting engine, but can't tell for sure. But I will see what I find about this Suite. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Candidates:

- A Visual dBase file, it that case it should be mainly ASCII text, but your question seems to rule that out.
- A (SAP) Business Objects Report file
- An Act! (CRM software) report file
- A Grand Theft Auto San Andreas game replay file.

Since you say it is 'used for report', [BO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Objects) is your best bet. It was acquired by SAP in 2007, before that it was standalone software produced by Business Objects AG.

So you probably need a copy of that to open the file.

Maybe there are other ways to inspect/use the file, [other people have faced the same problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=openbusiness+objects+rep+file)

Comment: Thanks for the list. Seems it is a reporting from the database itself, as it's called through a launcher I found. Unfortunatly the CodeReporter is discontinued, still I will ask the company, probably there are chances.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply without access to the source code, you have no way of knowing. None of the major third party Delphi reporting components (Quick Reports, Rave, Crystal, Report Builder, Fast Reports/Free Report) I'm aware of use *.rep as their default file extension. That isn't to say that the program authors didn't use one of these components, but opted to replace the tool's default extension with *.rep. There's also the possibility that the program's authors used their own custom and proprietary reporting system.

You could potentially take one of these .Rep files and try and load them into each Delphi reporting tool and see what the results are but I think your chances of success are exceedingly low.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Yeah I got that it's not easy and tried quite some reporting tools, but no success. Basically all I need are the SQL Queries that the reporting uses. Within HEX or Text Editor I don't see them. The database behind it is Codebase which we do have access, but there seems to be no query log, and no infos somewhere about the transaction log, that could be replayed but no sql queries found. Worst case is analysing database and doing own queries, but that's a lot of work to finally be able to do your own reporting.

Comment: Contact the owners of that product and buy the source code?... Just a thought.

Comment: Unfortunatly not available anymore.

Comment: Codereporter 2.0 from Codebase seems to be the correct one. Unfortunatly it's also discontinued...